# Normalization of the dataset, Error: all elements of input should be between 0 and 1

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have a problem with data normalization in PyTorch when I try to execute the training. First thing you need to know is that the dataset is composed of 3024 signal windows (so 1 channel), each one with a length of 5000 samples, so the dimension of the CSV file is 5000x3024. Each signal has 1 label that needs to be predicted.
Here is the code for how I load and normalize the data:

```
class CSVDataset(Dataset):
    # load the dataset
    def __init__(self, path, normalize = False):
        # load the csv file as a dataframe
        df = read_csv(path)
        df = df.transpose()
        # store the inputs and outputs
        self.X = df.values[:, :-1]
        self.y = df.values[:, -1]
        print("Dataset length: ", self.X.shape[0])
        # ensure input data is floats
        self.X = self.X.astype(np.float)
        self.y = self.y.astype(np.float)
        
        if normalize:
            self.X = self.X.reshape(self.X.shape[1], self.X.shape[0])
            min_X = np.min(self.X,0)  # returns an array of means for each signal window
            max_X = np.max(self.X,0)
            self.X = (self.X - min_X)/(max_X-min_X)
            min_y = np.min(self.y) 
            max_y = np.max(self.y)
            self.y = (self.y - min_y)/(max_y-min_y)
        
        # reshape input data
        self.X = self.X.reshape(self.X.shape[0], 1, self.X.shape[1])
        self.y = self.y.reshape(self.y.shape[0], 1)
        # label encode target and ensure the values are floats
        self.y = LabelEncoder().fit_transform(self.y)
        self.y = self.y.astype(np.float)

# prepare the dataset
def prepare_data(path):
    # load the dataset
    dataset = CSVDataset(path, normalize = True)
    # calculate split
    train, test = dataset.get_splits()
    # prepare data loaders
    train_dl = DataLoader(train, batch_size=32, shuffle=True)
    test_dl = DataLoader(test, batch_size=1024, shuffle=False)
    return train_dl, test_dl
```

While the train method is:

```
def train_model(train_dl, model):
    # define the optimization
    criterion = BCELoss()
    optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
    model = model.float()
    # enumerate epochs
    for epoch in range(100):
        # enumerate mini batches
        for i, (inputs, targets) in enumerate(iter(train_dl)):
            targets = torch.reshape(targets, (32, 1))
            # clear the gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            # compute the model output
            yhat = model(inputs.float())
            # calculate loss
            loss = criterion(yhat, targets.float())
            # credit assignment
            loss.backward()
            # update model weights
            optimizer.step()
```

The error that I get is in the line `loss = criterion(yhat, targets.float())` and it says:

```
RuntimeError: all elements of input should be between 0 and 1
```

I have tried inspecting the X in the variable explorer and it doesn't seem that there are any values that are not between 0 and 1. I don't know what I could have done wrong in normalization. Can you help me?

Comment: it's not the input - but rather the predicted `yhat` that is causing the error. check the prediction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Builtin loss functions refer to *input* and *target* to designate the *prediction* and *label* instances respectively. The error message should be understood as "input of the criterion" *i.e.* `yhat`, and not as "input of the model".

It seems `yhat` does not belong in `[0, 1]`, while [`BCELoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html) expects a probability, not a logit. You can either

- add a sigmoid layer as the last layer of your model, or
- use [`nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss.html) instead, which combines a sigmoid and the bce loss.